# AutoCompleteTextField itemFilter in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I have a list of courses and I need to filter them while searching
I need to be able to search for every word the user enters
For example: if I have course called nutrition basics, If I enter in search bar basics nothing show up but if i enters nut or even n it works.
Here is my code:
`itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion.name .toLowerCase() .startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),`
How can I do the filter as I want? I need to search even if for letter 'b' and still get the result nutrition basics.
I'm using flutter and firebase.

**Note: I tried contains insteadof startWith, but if i have two courses one nutrition basics and other math 500 basics and i searched for word basics the result shows after enter is only nutrition, also i need to be able to search for letters too, as b in basics or c..**
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have used method **startsWith**

```
itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion.name .toLowerCase() .startsWith(input.toLowerCase()),
```

use **contains** instead of **startsWith**

```
itemFilter: (suggestion, input) => suggestion.name .toLowerCase() .contains(input.toLowerCase()),
```

Comment: I tried it too before, but the suggestions doesn't show up if I do the above scenario of searching for a letter, even for a word basics

Comment: Can you please provide more code.

Comment: _results = _toBeFilteredList
        .where((elem) =>
            elem.name
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(query.toLowerCase()) ||
            elem.hS
                .toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(query.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();